# How to disable background linear gradient in CSS

Tags: css

```
.container-login100 { 
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #9053c7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
}
```

I'm trying to disable background linear gradient in CSS but it keep appear when I debugging. I tried deleted them still doesn't work.

Only disable from browser work for me.

**Browser Developer Tools**
[image: Browser Developer Tools]

Comment: Probably there is a compiler which set gradients from less or sass.

Comment: add `background:none!important` somewhere --- or clear your cache ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks ! Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the code in your css file > save it.

> .container-login100 { 
>       background: none !important; }

If you're using any cache plugin or anything which creates cache then please disable your cache properly.
If your cache is there then the code might not be implemented.